# Replacing an underscore in a certain position for a letter javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to replace the underscore at one set position with a letter. I've created a function to replace it at a specific spot but i'm unsure if I've referenced or if this will even work.

```
function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
        if(index = -1) {
            str = str;
        } else {
        str =  str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
        }
    }
underscore = replaceAt(underscore, word.indexOf(letter * 2), letter);
```

That's what I'm using at this point in time but it says it is undefined. Any Ideas? Full code below.

Thanks in Advance, I'm only new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

**Editted**

The code now looks like the code below and the snippet has been editted to the current code. Still not printing out the letters where I need them to be.

```
function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
        if(index != -1) {
            str =  str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
        }
        return str;
    }
underscore = replaceAt(underscore, word.indexOf(letter * 2), letter);
```

---

```css
/* Hangman Game CSS File */
body
{
 background-color: #1B264F;
}

#main {
 background-color: #5386E4;
 height: 97vh; 
    width: 95vw;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
canvas {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

/* colour scheme hex 

lightest blue: #5386E4;
middle blue: #274690;
darkest  blue: #1B264F;
black color: #070707;
white color: #E2E2E3;

*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hangman by Lachlan Teale</title> 
  <meta name="description" content="Lachlan Teale's Hangman Game 2015">
  <meta name="keywords" content="hangman, lachlan, teale, Javascript">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Lachlan Teale">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="main" width="1920" height="1080" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 //setting variables
  var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       var underscore = "";
       var letter;
       var complete = false;

 //list of words
  var wordList = ["apple", "peach", "pear", "mango", "banana", "paper", "pens", "laptop", "desk", "chair", "star", "sky", "moon", "sun", "planets"];

 //picking a random word from the list
  var word = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordList.length)];

 //print out the underscores for the number of letters
  for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
   var underscore = underscore + "_ ";
  }

  context.font = '50pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

    //correct letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Correct Letters", canvas.width * 0.08, canvas.height * 0.05);

    //Wrong Letter text
       context.font = 'bold 30pt Calibri';
       context.textAlign = 'center';
       context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
       context.text
       context.fillText("Wrong Letters", canvas.width - (canvas.width * 0.08), canvas.height * 0.05);

 //checking which button is pressed
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
   if ( event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90 ) {
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
          letter = String.fromCharCode( event.keyCode ).toLowerCase();
          context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
         context.fillText(letter, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.85);
        }
  });

 //checking if back key is pressed
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if ( event.keyCode == 8 ) {              
       context.clearRect(0, canvas.height * 0.80, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
      }
     });

 //function for replacing letter
  function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
      if(index != -1) {
       str =  str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
   }
   return str;
  }

 //checking if enter is pressed
       document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {                     
      if( event.keyCode == 13 ) {

    //checking if letter is in the word
       alert(word);

    alert(underscore + " " + letter + " " + word.indexOf(letter));

    underscore = replaceAt(underscore, word.indexOf(letter * 2), letter);

    context.clearRect(canvas.width * 0.4, canvas.height * 0.3, canvas.width *0.7, canvas.height * 70);
       context.font = '50pt Calibri';
         context.textAlign = 'center';
         context.fillStyle = '#E2E2E3';
         context.fillText(underscore, canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.70);

          
   }
     }); 

  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your function.

1. You're using `=` instead of `==` or `===`. `=` does an **assignment**, not a comparison.
2. You're never returning anything out of the function.

So correcting both of those:

```
function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
    if (index == -1) {
        str = str;
    } else {
        str = str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

But we don't need the first part of that at all, so:

```
function replaceAt(str,index,chr) {
    if (index != -1) {
        str = str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

Usage:

```
var str = "this is_a test";
var index = str.indexOf("_");
str = replaceAt(str, index, "|");
console.log(str); // "this is|a test"
```

It's worth noting that strings have a `replace` method as well, which will replace the first occurrence of a substring:

```
var str = "this is_a test";
str = str.replace("_", "|");
console.log(str); // "this is|a test"
```

Or all occurrences if you use a regular expression with the `g` flag:

```
var str = "this is_a test_with two underscores";
str = str.replace(/_/g, "|");
console.log(str); // "this is|a test|with two underscores"
```

Comment: May I ask what the final "return str" does?

Comment: @MrTeale: That's what determines the return value of the function. Assigning to `str` within the function just changes its value within the function, it doesn't do anything to the string you passed into the function.

Comment: It won't write the output to my canvas. I've set the function exactly out the same way you did and then just referenced the underscore variable and got nothing

Comment: @MrTeale Don't edit the code in your question once you've received answers, it invalidates them. This answers the question about how you replace the character in the string. If you have *another* question, post another question and maybe someone can help you. Try to make it as short as feasible.